# Postnikov tower of principal fibrations where all nth k-invariants vanish

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

Suppose a connected CW complex $X$ has a Postnikov tower where all fibrations $X_{n+1} \rightarrow X_{n}$ are principal (as Hatcher defines on page 412).

Let $k_{n}: X_{n} \rightarrow K(\pi_{n+1}X , n+2)$ denote the nth k-invariants of X (again, this is defined on page 412 Hatcher). Note, these maps correspond to elements of $H^{n+2}(X_{n};\pi_{n+1}X)$.

Then, Hatcher claims that " if all the $k_{n}$'s are zero, the $X$ is just the product of the spaces $K(\pi_{n}X,n)$".

The way Hatcher says this makes me think this is a trivial deduction from the above. But I am not sure how to conclude that $X$ is a product of spaces from it's Postinkov tower? Do you show somehow that $X$ is weakly equivalent to the product of the Eilenberg-Maclane spaces, and then invoke Whitehead's theorem?

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: You have that $X_{n+1} = \operatorname{hofib}(k_n : X_n \to K(\pi_{n+1}X,n+2)$, so if $k_n$ is trivial, this should be a trivial fibration, i.e. $X_{n+1} \simeq X_n \times \Omega K(\pi_{n+1}X,n+2)$

Comment: Ah yes, I forgot that homotopy fibres of fibrations are fibre homotopy equivalent to actual fibres. Thanks!